# Animating stroke-dashoffset with Angular?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, svg, angular-animations

[This is the original demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-bir8u8?file=src%2Fsvg-circle.component.css) and it animates the `stroke-dashoffset` using CSS, however only after the initial state is set or in other words on subsequent changes performed via the input field.

This is the CSS that animates the `stroke-dashoffset`

```
el-circle-progress circle {
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;
  fill: none;
}
```

However with that approach when the `percentage` property is set initially the stroke does not animate.

So i've tried to use Angular Animation to be able to trigger the animation whenever the `dashOffset` state is updated.

And this is the animation.

```
  animations: [
    trigger('animateStroke', [
      state(
        '*',
        style({
          transition: 'stroke-dashoffset',
        })
      ),
      transition('*<=>*', animate('1s linear')),
    ]),
  ],
```

And it's added in the template like this:

```
    <circle
      [@animateStroke]="dashOffset"
      id="percent"
      [ngStyle]="this.rotationTransform"
      [attr.cx]="center"
      [attr.cy]="center"
      [attr.r]="options.radius"
      [attr.stroke]="options.percentageStroke"
      [attr.stroke-width]="options.strokeWidth"
      [attr.stroke-dasharray]="circumference"
      [attr.stroke-dashoffset]="dashOffset"
      [attr.stroke-linecap]="options.strokeLineCap"
    ></circle>
```

[This is the full demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-olkg85?file=src%2Fmain.template.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Fsvg-circle.component.ts)

Now I did not do this right because no animation is triggered.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I don't know Angular, but I can see that your code sets `transition: stroke-dashoffset 0s ease 0s;` as an inline style on the circle (the style attribute). The original code doesn't do that. So, that inline style will override the style that you define in svg-circle.component.css.

Comment: Ah - hmmm - Yeah maybe there's a different way to animate the `stroke-dashoffset` ... Angular adds the timing animation via the `animate` call like this ... `animate('1s linear')` ... but maybe that's not taking effect due to the other defaults you are pointing out ....

Comment: There is nothing in standard CSS or JavaScript called `animate('1s linear')` (I know, you know that). The code is somehow transformed into `transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear;` and the only thing that happens when you change the value in the input element is that the attribute `stroke-dashoffset` is updated with a new value.

Comment: Yes `animate` is part of Angulars API.  It adds the animation type and timing to the animation angular coded `transition`.

Comment: But since you mentioned it ... I made a change to the call to `style` ... and it's this ... `'stroke-dashoffset': '*',` so just animate `stroke-dashoffset` .. period ... and this is the new demo ... https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e52ok1?file=src%2Fmain.template.html,src%2Fsvg-circle.component.ts

Comment: So now it works ... Kind of ... It animates when the input is changed ... Except it does not animate if we set the property to a static value like this ... `<el-circle-progress [options]="options" percentage="22"></el-circle-progress>
` the animation is not triggered ...

Answer (score 0):

OK - With the very helpful hints from Christian Wahl (From Denmark too, so you know the hints are good!!) I changed the animation style to:

```
'stroke-dashoffset': '*',
```

And now the animation works.  [Here's a new demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e52ok1?file=src%2Fmain.template.html,src%2Fsvg-circle.component.ts).

Now I just have to figure out how to get it to trigger for the initial value setting ...